# Can't find a way to animate a RotateTransform in a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, setter

I am trying to write a ControlTemplate for a button in XAML. In the Triggers collection I want to rotate one element of the button using a RotateTransform, which will get animated later (left the animation off for simplicity). To do this I need to refer to the Angle property of the rotations transform attached to the element of the button. And this is the problem: I can't seem to find a way to refer to it. Here is the code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myButtonTemplate"
                 TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse x:Name="OuterCircle"
                 RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.7,0.7">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.9" Color="DarkBlue"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="White"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="myTransform" Angle="0"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
        <Ellipse x:Name="InnerCircle"
                 RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
                 Stroke="DarkBlue"
                 >
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.35,0.35"
                                     RadiusX="0.7"
                                     RadiusY="0.7">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.05" Color="#70B0FF"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.9" Color="DarkBlue"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
        <Viewbox Margin="10">
            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="myTransform" Property="Angle" Value="90"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

</ControlTemplate>
```

I attempted to give the RotateTransform a name by x:Name="myTransform" and refer to it using it as the TargetName in a Setter. This didn't work. Other things a tried was "dotting down" like `TargetName="OuterCircle.RenderTransofrm.RotateTransform"`. No joy, either.

It seems that this ought to be easy, and probably is. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks, -- Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can access `myTransform` when you set `Storyboard.TargetName`:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myTransform"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                 To="90" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myTransform"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                 To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks, Clemens, your solution works! Just to enhance my personal learning experience: how would this work with a property trigger, where you can't use `Storyboard.TargetName`? In other words: is there a way to make the original example work? The charm of this would be that you only need one trigger on `IsMouseOver=True` instead of two EventTriggers.